# OpenMP creates only one thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I use Ubuntu and write several lines of code.But it creates only one thread. When I run on my terminal the `nproc` command, the output is 2. My code is below

```
int nthreads, tid;

#pragma omp parallel private(tid)
{
    tid = omp_get_thread_num(); 
    printf("Thread = %d\n", tid);

    /* for only main thread */
    if (tid == 0) 
    {
        nthreads = omp_get_num_threads(); 
        printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Thread = 0
Number of threads = 1
```

How can I do parallelism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using gcc/g++ you must make sure you enable `openmp` extensions with the `-fopenmp` **compiler** and **linker** options. Specifying it during linking will link in the appropriate library (`-lgomp`).

Compile with something like:

```
g++ -fopenmp myfile.c -o exec
```

or:

```
g++ -c myfile.c -fopenmp
g++ -o exec myfile.o -fopenmp
```

If you leave out the `-fopenmp` compile option your program will compile but it will run as if openmp wasn't being used. If your program doesn't use `omp_set_num_threads` to set the number of threads they can be set from the command line:

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 ./exec
```

I think the default is is generally the number of cores on a particular system.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad you got it going I amended my answer with more details. As well I also mention the OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable.

Comment: With GCC `omp.h` is not located on the default search path for include files unless `-fopenmp` is provided, therefore leaving the latter out will result in compile-time error. Also, the `-fopenmp -lgomp` combination is redundant - `libgomp` is linked in automatically when `-fopenmp` is present during link time (unless the link editor is called explicitly).

Comment: @HristoIliev   With recent version of GCC omp.h is actually included in the compilers include directory. In the case of Ubuntu and Debian (using GCC)for example if you do not include `-fopenmp` but do include `omp.h` the program will compile just fine. It will just disregard all the openmp pragmas. You are correct though when `-fopenmp` is specified -lgomp` is superfluous. However if you specify `-lgomp` your program will compile and link whether `-fopenmp` is used or not.

Comment: I will point out that not all compilers deal with openmp the same way GCC does however since the OP specified Ubuntu I targeted for that. I didn't mention clang because openmp support is rather new and you need a bleeding edge version to get openmp support.

Comment: You are right about `omp.h`. Still, if the program contains calls to the OpenMP runtime library (i.e. `omp_get_thread_num()`), it won't link unless `-fopenmp` or `-lgomp` is provided. Therefore, I would refrain from recommending someone to explicitly provide `-lgomp` as doing so could mask the case where `-fopenmp` is missing from the compiler options. Also, the name of the library could change with the future compiler versions.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks. I amended the first example where it was unneeded.