# OpenMP creating only one thread on Android

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm adding parallelism to a project with OpenMP and I already got it working on its Windows version (*with multiple threads running and time being saved*) but not on the Android one: OpenMP keeps using a single thread, instead of 4.

Let me put into context. I have a C++ project that is built to ARM using Clang 3.8, directly from the Visual Studio toolchain. The part of the project that uses OpenMP is the following method:

```
__inline static void func() {

    int requested_threads = 4;

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("/storage/emulated/0/test.txt");

    omp_set_nested(1);
    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_num_threads(requested_threads);

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(requested_threads)
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0) {
            myfile << "Number of threads = " << omp_get_num_threads() << "\n";
            myfile << "Max threads allowed = " << omp_get_max_threads() << "\n";
            myfile.close();
        }
        float x = pow(i, 10);
    }
}
```

To use OpenMP, I added `-fopenmp` in the C/C++ Command Line Additional Options and `-lgomp` in the Linker Command Line. I also included `libgomp.a` as an Additional Dependency. With that, the project is built successfully, generating a `.so` library.

That library is then used on a Xamarin C# project. All the parallelism is managed by the native C++ library, by means of OpenMP. The C# project will simply call it. The problem is that it only uses **1** thread, even though I'm asking for **4**. I've printed out the return of a few OpenMP runtime routines, as follows:

```
omp_get_num_procs() ........ 4
omp_get_dynamic() .......... 0
omp_get_nested() ........... 1
omp_get_max_threads ........ 4
omp_get_num_threads ........ 1
```

Apparently, it recognizes all 4 available cores of the phone. When the app is running, it uses up to 25% of the phone's CPU maximum.

I already did an extensive search but the closer I got was this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049965/openmp-creates-only-one-thread). I'm not sure why I can't get all cores running, maybe the OS is putting up some restriction or maybe I'm not referencing OpenMP correctly and it's not being used at all.

Comment: What kind of worksharing do you use in the C++ library? The code is always best, but at least some description.

Comment: @VladimirF I included the C++ test code in the question. Hopefully, that will clarify something.

Comment: Did you use `-fopenmp` at link time too. `-lgomp` isn&#39;t enough IINM (and `-lgomp` is implied by `-fopemp`)

Comment: @Gilles I used `-fopenmp` only at compile time, and `-lgomp` at link time. I now removed the `-lgomp` flag and nothing changed, which makes sense according to what you said (`-lgomp` is already implied by `-fopenmp`). I'm trying to add `-fopenmp` at link time too but it doesn't build, giving me the following error: **cannot find -lrt**

Comment: clang does not use `libgomp`, it uses its own `libomp`. Seems to me, that Android toolchain is not tweaked to support OpenMP in clang. But you can try to force it by using `-Xclang -fopenmp` instead of `-fopenmp`

Comment: @AlexeyBataev I added `-Xclang -fopenmp` on the Linking Command Line but I got the following warning: `argument unused during compilation: '-Xclang -fopenmp'`

Comment: This option is for the compiler, not for the linker. you need to provide it to clang itself. For the linker you should add something like `-lomp -L <path to libomp.so>`

Comment: @AlexeyBataev You should add your comment as the answer! Adding LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -lomp (besides the often cited LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fopenmp, LOCAL_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp, and LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fopenmp) to Android.mk made it link and work for me (NDK 18.0.5002713).